# GetBuiltProjectOutputRecursive error running Xamarin Forms iOS on Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, mono, xamarin.forms

Seems like I get this weird problem while running Xamarin.iOS on Visual studio.
This happened after I updated to the latest Xamarin (today).

I have connected to my Mac though. I tried to Google it, no answer...

"error MSB4057: The target "GetBuiltProjectOutputRecursive" does not exist in the project"

What is the problem? Before the update, it worked!

```
1>------ Build started: Project: GTS.Mobile.iOS, Configuration: Debug iPhoneSimulator ------
1>  Generated session id: 04dbf5285bd918e0f3e1fc41e6f65f8c
1>  Generated build app name: GTSMobileiOS
1>  Connecting to Mac server 192.168.9.164...
1>C:\Users\kkh\Computas\CargoNet\GTS.Mobile\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.21\build\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets(243,5): warning : All projects referencing GTS.Mobile.csproj must install nuget package Microsoft.Bcl.Build. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317569.
1>  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Runtime, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" from Version "1.5.11.0" [] to Version "4.0.0.0" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Xamarin.iOS\v1.0\Facades\System.Runtime.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
1>  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.IO, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" from Version "1.5.11.0" [] to Version "4.0.0.0" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Xamarin.iOS\v1.0\Facades\System.IO.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
1>  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Net.Http, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" from Version "1.5.0.0" [C:\Users\kkh\Computas\CargoNet\GTS.Mobile\GTS.Mobile\GTS.Mobile\bin\Debug\System.Net.Http.dll] to Version "4.0.0.0" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Xamarin.iOS\v1.0\System.Net.Http.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
1>  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Threading.Tasks, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" from Version "1.5.11.0" [] to Version "4.0.0.0" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Xamarin.iOS\v1.0\Facades\System.Threading.Tasks.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1819,5): warning MSB3276: Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly. Please set the "AutoGenerateBindingRedirects" property to true in the project file. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=294190.
1>  GTS.Mobile.iOS -> C:\Users\kkh\Computas\CargoNet\GTS.Mobile\GTS.Mobile.iOS\bin\iPhoneSimulator\Debug\GTSMobileiOS.exe
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.After.targets(59,36): error MSB4057: The target "GetBuiltProjectOutputRecursive" does not exist in the project.
```

Comment: Show your code.  Ask specific and directed questions.

Comment: I don't think I need to show any code. I created a new project. Linked with my Mac, sat iOS as startup project from the forms project and then I still get the error. I have checked If I have linked correctly as I could turn the iOS simulator remotely on my windows

Comment: I updated to the newest xamarin and got the same error, without changing anything else than updating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved the problem on my own installation.

Here is what i did:

1. Install the newest xamarin on both visual studio and mac.
2. Install xamarin studio (newest)
3. Remove all xamarin products including gtk.
4. Install xamarin newest(complete pack) with the installer
5. Reboot computer
6. Open solution and clean/build

Comment: hmmm so it works if I remove all gtk etc on my windows pc. then install the pack again and reboot and then try it on visual studio?

Comment: Thanks! I guess your solution is the simplest and the correct one.