# Build error: The target "_DetectSigningIdentity" does not exist in the project. (Visual Studio - Xamarin.IOS)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I am unable to build any xamarin project in Visual Studio 2017 mac.
It gives me the following error:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(81,81): 
Error MSB4057: The target "_DetectSigningIdentity" does not exist in the project. (MSB4057)
```

It was working fine before, i dont remember updating anything on my visual studio.
It is not specific to solution. None of my project gets build.

Any suggestions please??

Comment: maybe helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33828912/getbuiltprojectoutputrecursive-error-running-xamarin-forms-ios-on-visual-studio/33916850#33916850

Comment: I tried installing Xamarin Latest again, still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem on my own installation.

1. open update menu
2. select alpha channel
3. download and install all
4. restart

hope this helps